# How to get old image in edit form with VueJS?

Tags: vue.js

I'm unable to show old image in edit form. I have stored uploaded image in img folder inside public folder of laravel project.Below is my code for saving and editing form data. How can I display old uploaded image in edit form?
Please help me.

```html
   <input type="file" id="file-upload" @change="onFileChange" src="{{ asset('newapplicant.photo') }}">
```

Script

```js
save() {

const saveUrl = `/api/registration/${this.registrationId}/applicant`;
               VueAxios.post(saveUrl, this.formData, {
                       headers: {
                           'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                           Authorization: `Bearer ${window.localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
                       },
                   }, {
                       timeout: 10000,
               })
               .then((response) => {            
               if (response.status === 200 || response.status === 201) {
               this.applicant.push(response.data.data);
               this.successfulMessage = 'Successful.';
               this.clearAllData();
               }
               })
               .catch((error) => {                 
                   console.log(`api error:${error}`);
               });
            },
           edit(id) {
             const url = `api/registration/${this.$route.params.regId}/applicant/${id}`;
              VueAxios.get(url, {
                   headers: {
                       'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
                       Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}`,
                   },
               }, {
                   timeout: 100000,
               })
               .then((response) => {
                   // debugger;
                   this.newapplicant = response.data.data;
               });
           },
```

Answer (score 0):

one of the ways could be like this:

step1: in your .vue file, inside your **created** method, fetch your current image url

step2: keep that value in a separate property in your **data** object - say, *originalFile*

step3: do not bind your file-upload control directly to your new value. Use another **data** property for that - say, *currentFile*

step4: from your onchange handler, update your **currentFile** property and when the user uploads the new image, assign this new imageFile name/src to your **originalFile** property.

So, your code may look tentatively like this: 
(here's an extract from a project I recently worked on)

```
...
...
...
components: { DatePicker },
  data() {
    return {
      isLoading: false,
      imgFile: null,
      curImgUrl: "",
      filesSelected: 0
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.fetchUserPhotos();
  },
  methods: {
    handleFileChange: function(event) {
      if (!this.imgFile) {
        return;
      }
      // validate file size
      if (this.imgFile.size > 10000000) {
        U.showError("File larger than 10MB cannot be uploaded.");
        setTimeout(this.discardImage, 200);
        return;
      }
      let reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener(
        "load",
        function(e) {
          this.curImgUrl = e.target.result;
        }.bind(this)
      );
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.imgFile);
    },
    discardImage() {
      this.imgFile = null;
      this.curImgUrl = "";
    },
    fetchUserPhotos() {
      this.isLoading = true;
      PhotoService.getUserPhotos()
        .then(response => {
          this.userPhotos = response;
          this.isLoading = false;
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          this.isLoading = false;
          U.showError(error);
        });
    },
    savePhoto() {
      if (this.caption == undefined || this.caption.trim().length < 4) {
        U.showError("Please add a caption.");
        return;
      }

      U.showBusy();
...
...
...
```

And in your vue template you may do something like this:

```
<v-row justify="center">
                  <v-col cols="12">
                    <v-file-input
                      chips
                      label="Add Photo"
                      color="secondary"
                      accept="image/*"
                      persistent-hint
                      hint="max size: 2MB"
                      truncate-length="18"
                      v-model="imgFile"
                      show-size
                      @change="handleFileChange"
                      @click:clear="discardImage"
                      :disabled="isLoading"
                    ></v-file-input>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="12">
                    <v-layout justify-center>
                      <v-btn
                        small
                        class="mx-2"
                        color="error"
                        dark
                        :disabled="(isLoading || imgFile == null && imgFile == undefined)"
                        @click="discardImage"
                      >Discard</v-btn>
                    </v-layout>
                  </v-col>
                  <v-col cols="12" v-if="curImgUrl">
                    <v-img :src="curImgUrl" aspect-ratio="1.7" contain></v-img>
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
```

PS: I'm posting from my phone so the formatting may be a little messed up

Comment: For preview, you should use a separate image tag with it's src set to **curImgUrl**, or in your case, **asset('newapplicant.photo')**.